# AD Connect, Different UPN and email address

Tags: active-directory, office365

I have a domain where the email addresses are different to the UPN's. So in AD, I have a UPN of john.surname@domain.com and in Office 365, I have a UPN/email address of john@domain.com. I would like to sync these and am wondering what the best way to go about it is.

The AD UPN should remain and the email address in O365 should also remain. Could I just add a proxy address of john.surname@domain.com (current O365 email) along with the onmicrosoft one to AD and this would suffice?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: UPN's and email addresses are two different things. Can you clarify your question? Are you saying that the UPN on premises is different than the UPN in Office 365?

Comment: Don't seem to be able to add a comment, but yes that's correct. The UPN on premises is different than the UPN in Office 365 and I would like to keep the on premises UPN while keeping all the emails from the O365 account.

Comment: @Byrdwatcher1978 On a side note, you can ask, with the contact us below to merge your account, as the question was posted as a guest (user504106), unlike your comment which is not. (Byrdwatcher1978)

Comment: Hi, so I'm not sure what the best way to go is? I have a UPN on premise of john.surname@domain.com, in Office 365 the UPN is john@domain. I have synced already so the on-prem john.surname@domain.com UPN exists in office but without a valid Office 365 licence. I was thinking I would move the on premise account to a non-syncing OU, the account would then be deleted in Office 365. I would then rename the Office 365 UPN of john.surname@domain.com in Office 365 to the on-premise account, then move on-premise back to a syncing OU and then re-sync. Would this work and would all the emails remain?